# Vuetify: how to just apply border to component without the rest of stuff when using e.g. card

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a component, rendered using `v-row` and `v-col` that needs an unintrusive divider before the next `v-row`.

the idea is to render the divider using Vuetify styles, not my own due to consistency.

So I wanted to apply same styles as are used for `v-card` by specifying `class="v-card v-sheet"` and I got the border, with box-shadow.

But I also got all the other CSS, like margins and padding.

I looked in documentation trying to find something that would give me what I want, but I couldn't.

So, does Vuetify provide a CSS class that would ONLY declare `box-shadow` and `border-radius`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify does provide [Border-Radius](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/border-radius/) and [Elevation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/elevation/) utility classes. This allows you to compose a look similar to a `v-card` but without any other styles.

```html
<v-row class="rounded elevation-1">
</v-row>
```